# js support unicode emoji in explorer and chrome

Tags: javascript, unicode

I want to Unicode emoji with two codes in the browser,
for example:

```
U+1F476 U+1F3FB\\
```

i tried to use in `v="\u{1F476}\u{1F3FB}"`
but it doesn't decode in html, only I see the result in the console log.

I tried too to decode with `String.fromCodePoint(0x1F476 ,0x1F3FB)`
it work well in chrom but not in explorer.

how can I unicode in chrome and explorer too?

Comment: When you say "explorer" I assume you mean Internet Explorer. If so what versions are you working with?

Comment: my IE version: 11.0